# Regex containing both latin and cyrillic symbols

Tags: r, extract, rvest

I have the string I got from `html_text()`

> feel sore — болеть feel sore about — страдать; мучиться

But it should be like this

> feel sore — болеть 
>  feelsore about — страдать; мучиться

The problem is, `rvest` doesn't distinguish whitespaces from line breaks, but I need to get only the first line " feel sore — болеть" somehow.

I tried using `stringr::str_extract()` but failed. What do I do?

UPD: ok I've found out there's `html_text2()` but is it still possible to use regex?

Comment: Try `html_text2()` instead of `html_text()`

Comment: Is this coming from a website we can access?

Comment: @QHarr sure https://wooordhunt.ru/word/feel%20sore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two negative character classes:

- `[^—]+`: this matches any character that is **not** `—`one or more times
- `[^A-Za-z]+`: this matches any character that is **not** an upper- or lower case letter of the English alphabet one or more times:

Data:

```
str <- c("feel sore — болеть feel sore about — страдать; мучиться", 
         "so long — разг. Пока!")
```

Solution:

```
str_extract_all(str, "[^—]+—[^A-Za-z]+")
[[1]]
[1] "feel sore — болеть "                  "feel sore about — страдать; мучиться"

[[2]]
[1] "so long — разг. Пока!"
```

To get rid of the list character, use `unlist`; to get rid of the trailing whitespace, use `trimws`.

Comment: Strings like 'so long — разг. Пока!' are trimmed to 'so long — разг'. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, now it works pretty fine for me despite the fact I have no idea how it works haha. The pattern is `.*?—.*?[^A-z]+`

Comment: THanks for accepting. I've had second thoughts on the right solution though and have come up with this Better solution. NB: `[A-z]` is **not** the same as `[A-Za-z]`!